# Is there a faster way to do a group sql query?

Tags: sql, group-by

This query pulls from two separate tables. The video_thumb_chosen has a thumbcolumn that needs where the mode value needs to be selected.

```
$query = "SELECT DISTINCT videos.VIDEOID, 
                          videos.title,
                          (
                           select video_thumb_chosen.thumb
                           from video_thumb_chosen
                           where video_thumb_chosen.videoid = videos.VIDEOID 
                           group by video_thumb_chosen.thumb
                           order by count(video_thumb_chosen.thumb) desc limit 1 
                          ) as thumb, 
                          videos.rating, 
                          videos.runtime, 
                          videos.viewcount, 
                          videos.public, 
                          videos.time_added, 
                          videos.HD 
          FROM videos,video_thumb_chosen 
          WHERE videos.active='1' 
             && videos.tube=0  
             && videos.categories <> 7 
          ORDER BY videos.last_viewed desc limit $config[max_viewing_now]";
```

Comment: Specify your question a little bit more...

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: using mysql (ADONewConnection) database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing the cross join in the `from` clause would help:

```
FROM videos
```

You are not using video_thumb_chosen in the outer query, so there is no reason to include it.

There may be other optimizations as well.

Given what you are doing in MySQL, that will probably fix the problem.  Here is the query:

```
SELECT videos.VIDEOID, videos.title,
      (select video_thumb_chosen.thumb
       from video_thumb_chosen
       where video_thumb_chosen.videoid = videos.VIDEOID
       group by video_thumb_chosen.thumb
       order by count(video_thumb_chosen.thumb) desc limit 1
      ) as thumb,
      videos.rating, videos.runtime, videos.viewcount, videos.public, videos.time_added, videos.HD
FROM videos
where  videos.active='1' && videos.tube=0  && videos.categories <> 7
ORDER BY videos.last_viewed
desc limit $config[max_viewing_now]";
```

Comment: thanks it works faster, but its still a snail pace with another 2 queries similiar to this one on one page. Takes a minute to load at the moment.

Comment: apologies just cleared my browser data and restarted the browser and it worked a treat. Thanks